# Subscribe executed while getting error in angular 6

Tags: angular6, rxjs6

Recently I have upgraded angular 5 to angular 6 & as a result i have upgraded service code as follows:

```
register(postBody: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .post(this.remoteUrl + "auth/register", postBody)
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError("register", []))
  );
}

this.authService.register(this.formObj.value).subscribe(
    response => {

    }
)
```

Now when I am getting 400 error from the API. I am able to capture this error in error handler but still subscribe executed, why? Subscribe should be call only when getting response with no error.

I am new to this, but in angular 5 it was not happening. So Can anyone correct me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: What does `handleError` do? If it returns an `of` not `throw` observable, that swallows the error.

Comment: Thanks man. You are right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Subscribe lets you handle whatever comes back from your register function. But then why are you just catching errors you should at least map your result and return it when it's a success. Also I don't think that what you should do to catch and throw and error.

I hope this will help you

```
register(postBody: any): Observable<any> {
return this.http
  .post(this.remoteUrl + "auth/register", postBody)
  .pipe(
    map(data => data), //this will return the response when success
    catchError(this.handleError(err =>{
        //Here you can do something like
         err.code === 404 
         ? throwError("Not found")
         : throwError(err)
    }) 
  );
}

this.authService.register(this.formObj.value).subscribe(
    response => {
      // Do stuff whith your result
    },
    err => {
      // Do stuff whith your error
    },
    () => {
      // Do stuff after completion
    },
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Why it was not marked as correct?